# How to check if the data is saved in server using post method in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, post, server, save

I got this code to check whether I get the connection upon calling the url from the one that I deployed using rails:

```
Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
```

and it returns "OK" but that's not what I was looking for. What I wanted was to get a response if my entry was saved or not. How can I get that kind of response?

Like for instance, I entered an existing username and it returns OK but it wasn't save since the OK means the connection was fine. I wanted to be informed that the data wasn't saved because of duplicate username.

I am using console in vb for practice.

I am new to this by the way, please be nice.

Comment: the service would need to be changed to return a different status code for those scenarios.

Comment: @5uperdan what service that has to change? i tried this too and it returned 200 >> Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)

Comment: Status code 200 is 'OK'. The service you're calling must be changed to return a different status code. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
This isn't something you can fix in your vb console app. If the service returns OK for all queries then that's all you'll ever get.

Comment: You may want to read up on the subtle differences between POST and PUT. If you just want to replace the user it sounds like you may actually want a PUT operation.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you need throw a custom error from server

```
Dim oNewMessage As New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented)
oNewMessage.Content = New StringContent("This is your custom text")
Throw New HttpResponseException(oNewMessage)
```

But, take care, because that custom message can be 'reseted' by IIS. Put this in your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This may "Leaves the response untouched if an existing response exists", according to MSDN (http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors).